# Possible dimension-5 interaction beyond the standard model

Tags: standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

Consider the following dimension-5 interaction:

$$\bar{\psi}D^{2}\psi.$$

Why is this interaction not consistent with either Lorentz invariance, the standard model field content or gauge invariance?

Comment: What do you mean by "dimension-5 interaction"? Do you mean the mass dimension of that term is 5? Your question also suggests that you have reason to believe this interaction is "not consistent" to begin with - if you draw from another source here, please cite that source, and in any case explain where this belief comes from.

Comment: by dimension-5 interaction, I mean that the mass dimension of the interaction is 5.

Comment: To me this seems like a diagram of the type:     
e^+ + e^-  --> gamma gamma     
and that is a perfectly fine (loop-)interaction that should be described by the above term as an effective operator. So I just think it is not considered because it is a rather standard interaction